# Single firebase login for all users

Tags: firebase, authentication, firebase-authentication, password-protection

I'm currently developing a web app using firebase authentication to make sure only authorized users can access the backend (e.g. firestore).

However, I don't really care about differentiating users but just want a single password based login/authentication. Meaning users come to the site, enter the password they know and then they get access to the protected data (e.g. from firestore). No need to create a own account.

However, I don't think firebase auth supports something like that.
What would likely work is just using .htaccess to protect the page and then provide users with anonymous accounts once they can access the app/page.
However, the browser popup caused by this is not nice enough for my purpose, I would prefer a nicely styled password form in the actual browser window.

What I could try is creating one account and sharing the password for that with all users (and set the email in the background). However, I'm not sure whether this works fine (e.g. multiple users being logged in at the same time on the same account).

Am I missing a simple option to implement such a single password based login shared between users?

Or is it e.g. possible to send a password to cloud functions, check it there and return an access token for an anonymous account from there to the user?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just create a single Firebase Auth email/password account and share the credentials with everyone.  As long as you trust that each user will not share them with anyone else, and you trust that they will not maliciously overwrite each others' data, it should be fine.

Comment: Perfect, its just for a small wedding website with limited guests, main purpose is to have it not completely open in the world but have at least some kind of protection while being simple to use.

I'll try it this way, thank you very much for the prompt feedback!